# USB device not recognised - windows 8.1

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm a beginner with Arduino and i have acquired the Arduino UNO R3 board. i have followed the instructions on arduino website in order to install the board, however it fails and still remains as an unrecognised device.

**consequently, arduino IDE reports that COM1 is not found, and the 'ports' menu is grayed out.**

steps i have tried:

**1) install the Arduino 1.0.5 IDE** 
   
- the installation failes near the end when installing the arduino board

**2) install the Arduino 1.5.7 BETA IDE**

- the installation is successful but arduino device is still unrecognized.

**3) i have tried manually installing the drivers by letting windows search in the arduino IDE installation folder/drivers/** 

- it reports that the best driver is already installed - "usb unrecognized device"

**4) i have tried installing the drivers by manulally loading the `.inf` files from the IDE installation folders, and installing all the `serial converter A/B/C/D` in the list** 
- all failed to install.

i have done all the above for both IDE 1.0.5 and 1.5.7b with windows installer And zipped files, under administrative rights in windows 8.1

How do i get this to work?

Comment: Is your board connected to COM1?

Comment: well thing is, i connect to this board via USB and i honestly dont know what 'port1' is. the windows device manager does not recognize and is unable to install the arduino driver, thus unable to create any ports for it

Comment: Ah, well then. Does it show up as an unknown device in device manager?

Comment: yep, it does indeed

Comment: You said you loaded the .inf files, the guide mentions to just load up Arduino UNO.inf. I'm guessing you tried that?

Comment: yes, the `arduino.inf` file according to the device manager, does not contain any relevant information. i have oppened the file and it does indeed contain what i need, but device manager says it doesnt

Comment: After a quick google, would this help? [link](http://mytechblog.com/tutorials/arduino/install-arduino-drivers-on-windows-8/)

Comment: Is this an official board? If so, you might have to contact Arduino and ask for a replacement. Other than that: another computer, another USB cable, make sure the right COM port/board is selected...

Comment: i am going to disable driver sign check as per doowy advice, and i will try it on a different pc too. how do i know if the board is official?

Comment: nothing worked, i guess my board is just faulty. thanks for the help guys

Comment: I have solved my issue. its funny, since i have got a new genuine kit, but the usb cable was faulty. i changed to some other usb cable i had laying around, and it worked perfectly...

Comment: Maybe you typed something in wrong somewhere; your `Shift` key appears to be having problems.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat if you are referring to the inconsistency in capitalization, dont mind it. i never care about correct capitalization. and no, i am pretty sure it was the cable. i never make case-sensitive mistakes where it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by changing my USB cable. the cable in the kit was new and seemed to supply power to the arduino board, but windows was unable to identify the board using that cable. maybe the data wires were damaged.

 in any case, i changed the cable and everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem.

**1.** connect your Arduino board to the PC / Laptop.
**2.** open control panel. and go to **view devices and printers**

**3.** Here You can see a **unknown device**... i.e. your arduino board. double click on it.
[image: Unknown device]
**4** Click on hardware..................................................
[image: Hardware]
**5.** Now Choose **Update Driver**... Choose the location where the **Arduino IDE is installed**... And go to **Next**
**6.** Now your computer will recognise your arduino board

Answer (score 0):

Right click on devices list from Manager
update driver and choose the folder with name "driver" in your arduino IDE app that you use
Ok 
and the card ll be recognized 
good luck